# Updating custom product meta box field - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, meta

I'm trying to update a custom product meta box field using the updating system from WooCommerce core. Here is my code:

The new field Shipping info

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'my_product_options_shipping' );
function my_product_options_shipping() {
    global $post;
    $shipping_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_shipping_info', true );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_shipping_info',
            'value'       => $shipping_info,
            'label'       => __( 'Shipping info', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'Shipping in two days', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    );
}
```

And this is the function that adds the new field as prop in WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::save

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'my_admin_process_product_object' );
function my_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    $product->set_props(
        array(
            'shipping_info' => isset( $_POST['_shipping_info'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_shipping_info'] ) ) : null,
        )
    );
}
```

I think I'm missing a step. Shouldn't it be saved automatically from function WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::save which is attached to woocommerce_process_product_meta?

**EDIT**

I found the missing step. I need to add my custom post meta in the protected array $extra_data from abstract class WC_Data.

I'm not too good at OOP, so how I can access that array to push my custom data?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're just doing `$shipping_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_shipping_info', true );`
So why not save the trouble and just use `update_post_meta`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'my_admin_process_product_object' );
function my_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_shipping_info',  wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['_shipping_info'] ) ) );
}
```